# Swap memory not working

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I work on a workstation Precision 7920 Tower Workstation in which I had recently upgraded the RAM from 96 GB to 416 GB (previously it had 12 dimms of 8GB and I added 10 dimms of 32 GB each)   while installing I thought the swap memory is of no use as I had a lot of RAM for usage. I asked the technician for removing the swap memory. Later during simulation of a process, the time consumption was more so while trying things I again installed the swap and it started working well.
Again the problem arised and I suspected it was due to the reboot in the system. So I removed and installed the swap memory again and it started working well again.
I searched for the solution it said to add a line in the /etc/fstab but the line was already there. I tried to reboot and check the but the swap wasn't working ( the time was same as without the swap) but when I try *free -h* command on the terminal it shows the allocated swap memory. So what might be the problem with the swap?
Result for the *vmstat 1 5*
[image]

Comment: What is the result of command `vmstat 1 5`

Comment: I couldn't post the result here, is there anyway I can send you the output?

Comment: Edit your answer and add the text there.

Comment: I just did, thanks.

Comment: I do not see any swap usage. What is  the value of swappiness?

Comment: I have allocated swap memory of 96GB currently.

Comment: I see it. The question is what is the value of swappiness: `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

Comment: It shows 60 for swappiness.

Comment: So for me it seems like your system do not need swap. You can see in `vmstat` there are no `si` or `so` activities.

Comment: We are running a time series simulation. With the swap of 96 GB the time for running simulation of one time step takes 0.22 second without swap it is taking 0.59 seconds. With this I inferred that the swap might be working.

Comment: It's hard to capture the status of the machine in the moment when it is loaded. And swap is used when needed, not all the time.

Comment: Could you post the line mentioning the swap that you said having found in your fstab ? I am left surprised that the file used for swap displays a priority of -2. Default when creating is -1. How did you create that swapfile ? (mkswap ? dd ?…) and what is the underlying filesystem (ext4, Btrfs, other ?)

Comment: *With the swap of 96 GB the time for running simulation of one time step takes 0.22 second without swap it is taking 0.59 seconds.* Are you absolutely sure about that? Your data indicates you system doesn't touch swap at all. Unless you've run `swapoff -a` your swap usage if it was non-zero earlier, shouldn't be zero now. The kernel will **never** evict swapped pages from swap back to RAM unless you ask it to and I'm 99.99999% sure your system has a ton of processes which would have been swapped out if the kernel actually needed it.